# Scheduled for an interview and given option to send my resume

Tags: interviewing, resume

Through networking I am scheduled for an interview. The person told me I can send my resume if I want. Since the point of a resume is to get an interview, is it worth sending? In a certain sense it could only hurt my chances since I already have the interview. The job will hire base off experience, not awards or school etc. so I think sending my resume wouldn't add much. OTOH it just seems more normal to send my resume.

Comment: Contact telling you you can send your resume is polite version of asking you to send your resume (if you want the job). Not doing it would come off unprepared/unprofessional. E.g.: the guy that had the nerve to show up for the interview without even an up-to-date resume.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.   Send it.    It will give them a chance to look at it, be prepared, and have questions.   I've been in interviews where the interviewer had no idea what to ask, and it was uncomfortable.    Besides questions, it will help them to be prepared to give information on the type of job you'd be good for.

Answer (score 2):

As a hiring manager, I used resumes to determine who to offer interviews to. You are correct about that. However, I also used them to come up with questions that were particular to individuals.

A resume can highlight import aspects about you that you want the manager to know about. The kind of things that you excel at. The kind of things that if they ask you questions about them then you will get excited and authoritative in your responses to them.

Your fear that they may in fact withdraw the interview is also rather unlikely. Even if they see something that is a red flag, at this point it would have to be serious to cancel. They will instead probe you on it in the interview. So send the resume.

Answer (score 1):

> Since the point of a resume is to get an interview, is it worth sending?

Actually, the point of a resume is to get to know the candidate a little bit (which could then result in interest and an interview).

I say it is worth sending, as it will show interest from your part, and also enable them to get a better idea of the experience you list on your resume (giving you higher chances of getting their attention).

It seems that you have your resume already prepared so I say you go for it and send it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried that submitting your resume might hurt your chances then you may not be right for the job, and that will come out in short order if you start working there. It's probably best to find out beforehand than after the fact.

If for nothing else other than completeness sake, I'd suggest submitting it.